# How to get portal email notification address

Tags: liferay

I have it in control panel/portal settiongs/email notifications.
And i need to get it programmatically in my Controller, but i don't know how. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
themeDisplay().getCompany().getEmailAddress()
```

Comment: I get admin@CompanyEmail but it' defaul.

Comment: Is there someone that knows how to get portal setings programmatically

Answer (score 0):

In 6.1.x you should be able to use :

```
PortalUtil.getEmailFromAddress(...)
```

But in 6.0.x you need :

```
PrefsPropsUtil.getString(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(),PropsKeys.ADMIN_EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS);
```

more info from there : http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11090283